# Log4Net stacktrace vs stacktracedetail

Tags: log4net

Question 1 : What is the difference between stacktrace parameter in Log4Net and the stacktracedetail?

Question 2 : What is the stacktrace level that one can specify as described [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)?

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1, the [page you link to](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) shows the difference between stacktrace and stacktracedetail: stacktracedetail includes parameter information.

```
stacktrace  
…

Output uses the format: type3.MethodCall3 > 
                        type2.MethodCall2 > 
                        type1.MethodCall1

stacktracedetail    
…

Output uses the format: type3.MethodCall3(type param,...) >
                        type2.MethodCall2(type param,...) > 
                        type1.MethodCall1(type param,...)
```